# How to flex a div with position fix?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get a page with 2 main elements, one side-panel that takes 20% of the viewport width and has the position fixed and the other would be the main window, taking 80% of the remaining space.

However it seems that giving the side panel a `position: fix; top: 0` removes all of its flex properties.

Desired behavior: How can you manage to place a side panel in a proportional width of the screen and also have it keep its position fixed at top:0 ?

Note: It would be best if I could not use `position: sticky`

Here's a codepen to help. https://codepen.io/phil94/pen/vYORpMj

`

```css
#side-panel {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed ;
  background: #acacac;
  border: solid 3px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

#container {
  background: #3687d7;
  display: flex;
}

#main {
  background: #acacac;
  border: solid 3px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<app>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="side-panel">
      <ol>
        <li>Tomatoe</li>
        <li>Bananas</li>
        <li>Pickles</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </div>
</app>
```

Comment: what you need is position:sticky, not fixed : example forked from your pen https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYGaGdo

Comment: For some reason I never got `position: sticky` to work on my vue.js app. Is there a way to get this done with `position: fixed` ?

Comment: then you need to look at a polyfill  that reset position coordonates while scrolling (based on position:relative;) If you use position:fixed; you need to put static element away from the area used by the fixed element. example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjdZdpr width:20%->margin-left:20%

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: This solution works for me. Didn't think of putting margin in %.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `position: sticky;`

```
#side-panel {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  background: #acacac;
  border: solid 3px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}
```